# Given city and state, how to get the nearest zip code in US

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

We have a situation where user enters a city, state for which we need to find a corresponding zip code. In case there is no corresponding zip code, we are required to find a zip code that close to the city, state.

Can you please throw some ideas as to how to go about doing this using Google maps/geocode API.

**EDIT:** Is it possible for US that a city entered by user does not have a zip code?

Comment: Is this for a particular country, or worldwide?  If the US (or probably other counties), many cities will have multiple zip codes--does that matter to you or is any zip code close to that city OK?

Comment: @neuhausr If we get multiple zip codes, we will prompt the user to choose one of them.

Comment: The Google Maps API geocoding service will only return a zip code if you give it a street address. Giving just the City and State won't return a zip code, most likely because there are usually multiple zipcodes per city (in the US at least).

Comment: Every city has at least one ZIP code

Comment: @MohanGundlapalli did you get a scenario, where reverse geocoding with google maps was not giving postal code. For e.g. in my case its not giving postal code for Xi'an, Shaanxi, China when i find using reverse geocoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you could do something with http://www.geonames.org API for getting back zipcodes with cities ands states.

In case it is not found, you could use the [geoname parameter postalcode_startsWith](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html) and propose results to your user or to you.

But first of all, I would study how the zipcode is built on the country you are working on. Once this done, you could maybe get back more accurate data from geonames API.

Comment: We got the zip codes from geonames for all the cities of US. This helps to get zip code(s) of any city. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I created a simple API to do that magic using Google Maps Geocoding API.

**Github**: https://github.com/t4joel/get-address-by-google-maps-api

[image]